# Find the plot of $y=1+\cos t$, $x=\sin^2t$.

Tags: calculus, geometry, parametric

I'm trying to find the plot for the following :

$$y=1+\cos t, x=\sin^2t$$

I'm trying to get ride off variable $t$.

This is what I done for some reason is incorrect :

$$x=\sin^2t=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\cos 2t}{2}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2\cos^2t-1}{2}=-\cos^2t+1$$

We know that :

$y=1+\cos t \rightarrow y-1=\cos t$

Therefore

$$x=-\cos^2t+1=-(y-1)^2+1 \rightarrow x=-(y-1)^2+1$$

But for some reason I get the wrong plot.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean you get the wrong plot?

Comment: It should be $x=-(y-1)^2+1$ after substituting for $\cos{t}$. Could that have anything to do with it, or was it a typo?

Comment: @abel I checked on www.wolframalpha the plot for $$x=(y-1)^2+1$$ and the plot for $$y=1+\cos t, x=\sin^2t.$$ are not the same

Comment: @user242774, see my answer.

Comment: @architectpianist typo, but it still incorrect I edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have the parametric equation $$y = 1 + \cos t, x = \sin^2t.$$  eliminating $t$ using the fact $\sin^2 t + \cos ^2 t = 1,$ we get  $$(y-1)^2 + x = 1 $$ the graph is a parabola in the first quadrant with axis of symmetry at $y = 1,$ with vertex at $(1,1).$

Comment: Thank you for you answer, can you explain how do you use the fact that $sin2t+cos2t=1$ inorder to solve this? I can't see it.

Comment: Also I don't quite understand why the equation I reach to which is : $$x=−(y−1)^2+1$$ has a different plot then yours equation $$(y−1)^2+x=1$$ these are the same equation, you just moved the expression $-(y-1)^2$ to the left side.

Comment: the range of $x$ is $[0,1]$ and the range of $y$ is $[0,2].$

Answer (score 0):

As you have already obtained, the third parametric variable $t$ can be easily eliminated by substituting $\cos t=y-1$ in the second relation $x=\sin^2 t$, we get $$x=1-\cos^2 t=1-(y-1)^2 \implies (y-1)^2=-(x-1)$$ Now, compare the above equation with the standard equation of the parabola $Y^2=-4AX$ (having X-axis as its axis & sides opening in negative X-direction), we have $Y=y-1$, $x=x-1$ & $A=\frac{1}{4}$. Thus, the parabola has its vertex is at $V\equiv(y-1=0, x-1=0)\equiv(1, 1)$ & its focus at $S\equiv\left(x-1=-\frac{1}{4}, y-1=0\right)\equiv(\frac{3}{4}, 1)$

Find out the points of intersection of parabola with the x-axis by setting $y=0$ in the equation as $(0, 0)$ & similarly, the points of intersection of parabola with the y-axis by setting $x=0$ in the equation as $(0, 0)$ & $(0, 2)$

Now, the curve of the parabola can be easily plotted by locating

Step 1: Specify the vertex V & the focus S & join them to get the axis of parabola (as shown by the dotted line in the figure below)

Step 2: Specify the points of intersection of the parabola with the co-ordinate axes & take the length of latus rectum $4A=1$

Step 3: Draw, though these points, both the arms of parabola opening in the negative x-direction. (As shown in the figure below manually drawn)

[image: plot of parabola]